# When winterba.sh is blocked the sites become unusable

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2012

When `winterba.sh` is blocked by over zealous network administrators the sites are unusable.

Pages time out or take a very long time to load.

You can't even opt out of the hats as that requires opening a page from `winterba.sh`.

*Posted on behalf of Thomas Owens who is suffering at the moment.*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It wasn't winterba.sh itself being blocked that was the problem, but cdn.prom.sstatic.net (our promo CDN subdomain). That's where the Winter Bash JavaScript file is loaded from.

This file was loaded synchronously and thus blocking, which should almost always be avoided, especially when loading something peripheral like this, where synchronous loading is unnecessary. The domain being actively blocked made this fairly obvious, but it had a performance impact for *all* users.

The script is now being loaded asynchronously everywhere, so the timeout when trying to load the JS file isn't going to impact the rest of the functionality.

Comment: Many thanks. I can now actually use SE sites with my insane proxy/filter at work.